# How does this app ask for background location permission immediately?

Tags: ios, core-location

My understanding since iOS 13 is that background location permissions can *only* be granted by the user after they have already granted foreground location permissions, and the app is in the background, when a location event which would have triggered the app's background location occurs. At that point they get a dialog something like:

> Allow “App” to also access your location even when you are not using the app?

Every app I've used has the same behaviour, except one app, which is able to present that dialog *immediately* after asking for the foreground location permission dialog:

[image: Background location permission dialog in-app]

How does this app immediately and repeatedly trigger the background location dialog like this?

Comment: You ask for "always" after you have asked for and received "When in use". I do the same thing [in my app](https://apps.apple.com/au/app/where-was-i/id1523748405)

Comment: Are you sure about that @Paulw11? Every resource on Stack Overflow and elsewhere suggests the background location dialog only ever appears when the app is in the background.

Comment: Yep, as I said, I do it.

Comment: I've just tested, I'm surprised it works! (More that I couldn't find any information on it.) If you want to add an answer, I'll mark as solved.

Comment: Well keep in mind this didn’t start until iOS 13.4. Before that, there was no immediate second dialog.

Comment: Ah right, that explains all the threads I found from the launch of iOS 13 without any solutions provided, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your app has asked for and received "when in use" authorisation it can then ask for "always" authorisation to trigger a second permission dialog. This behaviour requires iOS 13.4 or later.

You should consider the user experience.  I suggest that your app explains why it needs always authorisation before asking for it, otherwise the user may be peppered with permission requests

Comment: “it can then ask for "always" authorisation to trigger a second permission dialog.” In iOS 13.4 or later.

Comment: Thanks Matt. I didn't know that it required 13.4

Answer (score 0):

In my case it didn't work at first, because I tried to get permission for 'always' twice.
Here's a snippet for code-lovers:

```
let locationManager = CLLocationManager()
locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
```

So it's important to use `WhenInUse` here! Then when the user grants access, you can ask for always:

```
func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didChangeAuthorization status: CLAuthorizationStatus) {
    switch status {
    case .authorizedWhenInUse, .authorized:
        locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
        fallthrough
    case .authorizedAlways:
        ... //(do your business here)

    }
}
```