# How can I reliably determine if I can request background location permission from the user?

Tags: ios, core-location

In iOS, location permissions can either be granted "when in use" or "always".

If the current status of location permissions is `notDetermined`, I believe that calling `requestWhenInUseAuthorization()` or `requestAlwaysAuthorization()` will *always* trigger a permission request dialog to the user and that the `locationManager(_:didChangeAuthorization:)` delegate method will *always* be called after the user selects one of the options in the permission request dialog. As far as I know, this is correct across all versions of iOS as long as the app is correctly configured (please correct me if I'm wrong).

However, if the app has previously requested, and has been granted, the "when in use" permission, it should still be possible to request "always" permission from the user (except in iOS 13 prior to iOS 13.4, where it "grants" the permission immediately) as long as the "always" permission hasn't previously been requested.

My questions are:

1. If the current state of the location permission is `authorizedWhenInUse`, how can I know if calling `requestAlwaysAuthorization()` will have an effect? Alternatively, can I determine if the permission dialog was shown after requesting it?
2. If the above does result in a permission dialog shown to the user, how can I determine when the user made a decision, if they decided to *not* grant always location? (The delegate method isn't called because the permission status doesn't change.)

<sup>I can think of a hacky way of achieving at least (1), by separately storing when I make attempts to the various permission requests, but this could fail for a variety of reasons, and wouldn't be useful if an older version of the app had already shipped which didn't record this.</sup>

---

The reason I'm asking is that I have permission onboarding screens for each type of permission, and I only want to navigate to the next screen after the user has finished granting access to the "when in use" and "always" permission dialogs separately (which is the best way of requesting it if you want immediate background location access [in iOS 13.4 and later](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64534309/how-does-this-app-ask-for-background-location-permission-immediately)). Therefore, I need to reliably know when the user has made a decision on both dialogs, hence (2).

For added resiliency and to account for edge cases, I want to know whether or not to skip the location onboarding screen altogether if the location permission can not be requested, knowing that it's possible that "when in use" has already been granted, but "always" might not yet have been requested, hence (1).

Comment: Yes, all the other frameworks that need user authorization have a `requestAuthorization` method that takes a completion handler, so you know what happened because the completion handler is called. But Core Location, for no reason that I can see, does not use that architecture; instead, you are expected to just try to use location services and meanwhile ask for authorization if it is needed and just see what happens.

Comment: You should get `willResignActive`/`didBecomeActive` events as the request dialog is shown, but this is also a bit of a hack.  In my app, I just track whether I have asked for "alwaysl in user defaults. If I haven't asked and have "when in use" then I ask for always.  If I have asked and have "when in use" I show a link to the app settings screen where the user can make the change.